# Why does Intellij go to a blank page when switching to a new changelist?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-17

As of Intellij 2017.3.4, I've noticed an odd and annoying behavior of Intellij whenever I switch to a new local changelist. When creating a new changelist and setting it as my active changelist, the IDE removes the file that I'm currently looking at from my current view, and I see the gray background that one sees before having selected a file for editing. Is there a way to disable this and keep the file that I'm looking at on the screen when changing to a new changelist?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Task context tracking feature. When you create a new changelist, clear the Tack context checkbox.